# getting random testimonial in magento not working due to cache

Tags: magento, testimonials

```
I am trying to display random testimonials, but due to magento cache the random is not working, i have to flush the cache each time to see the testimonials change, my code

 public function getTestimonialsLast(){
        $collection = Mage::getModel('testimonial/testimonial')->getCollection();
        $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('status',1);
        $collection->setPageSize(5);
        return $collection;
    }
```

how can i make it work , how can i make it so that whenever the page is refreshed the collection is randomized.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance,

Comment: In which Block do you use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is in the view file:

You can stop Magento from caching the block by adding a **false** parameter when you implement the block.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('testimonials', false) ?>
```

Because of

```
Method Summary 
string getChildHtml ([string $name = ‘’], [boolean $useCache = true], [ $sorted = true])
```

---

Or you could add the cache lifetime to your testimonial class:

```
public function getCacheLifetime() { return null; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you caching the block within the modules public function __construct()

It would have information on 'cache_lifetime'

Removing the cache block would prevent it from being cached and perform a fresh call each time.

Comment: No, there is no information on 'cache_lifetime' and within the modules  public function __construct() {
  $this->init('testimonial');
 }